# Automatic refreshing tableview without pulling to refresh

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I want to know how to automatically refresh a tableview without having to pull down to refresh. So I tried setting an `NSTimer` and calling a function that has `reloadData()`. But that did not work. In other words, I did:

```
@IBOutlet weak var allPrayerRequestsTableView: UITableView!

var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func update() {
    allPrayerRequestsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

But this did not work. Anybody know how to automatically refresh a tableview every few seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to reload your tableview in main thread this way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.allPrayerRequestsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

And your method will be:

```
func update() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.allPrayerRequestsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Sample code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var allPrayerRequestsTableView: UITableView!
    var tableArray = [Int]()
    var count = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        allPrayerRequestsTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        allPrayerRequestsTableView.delegate = self
        allPrayerRequestsTableView.dataSource = self

        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return tableArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(tableArray[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }

    func update() {
        count++
        //update your table data here
        tableArray.append(count)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.allPrayerRequestsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hm... it's not working... I'm assuming I am still using the timer variable?

Comment: Ok I will share sample project.

Comment: Great! Worked as it should! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 3):

I believe simply using `allPrayerRequestsTableView.reloadData()` will not really update or refresh your table view. You will need to update the data source of the table view, then perform the `reloadData()` method afterwards.

Try this:

```
func update() {
    /**
       ADD THE CODE TO UPDATE THE DATA SOURCE
    **/
    allPrayerRequestsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did your update gets invoked? If not,a possible reason: normally your app runs at NSDefaultRunLoopMode mode, when you are scrolling your tableview, runloop switches its mode to UITrackingRunLoopMode at which timer is denied, when you stop,runloop returns to default mode.

So my suggestion is that add your timer to runloop mode kCFRunLoopCommonModes and check if this works.

```
let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: "update:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an update method that calls himself again and again, then call it once in ViewDidLoad. For example:

```
-(void)reloadMethod{
    [self.allPrayerRequestsTableView reloadData];

    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 4.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self reloadMethod];
    });
}
```

This will update your table view every 4 seconds.

Comment: is't possible to block or stop this activity after some times.